# How to Select an opion from a Google Forms popup dropdown Puppeteer NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, selector, puppeteer

everybody, I have recently been trying to implement automation for a google form and I'm stumped with this dropdown.

I simply have been unable to select the value I want from the popup dropdown. As the dropdown autocompletes if I use puppeteer to write in the field ie. United *space* Kingdom it autocompletes the form to United Arab Emeries (the first value after United) as when the space character is used, it enters on the form and selects the first value.

I have made a dummy google form to simulate my scenario:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeY-5GpBQ7ww3qm-EUn5ENTl-KOVD02PIwlyblw8ItjfOfhtQ/viewform?usp=sf_link

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try and this is what i code.

NOTES:

I'm not code this by clicking and selecting element by normally mouse method, because it's really hard to debug when it's gone error.

You have to declare the root selector of the dropdown, and if there are multiple dropdown, you have to find the right selector by yourself.

And don't forget to select the `desiredOption` in this code.

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer')

const formURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeY-5GpBQ7ww3qm-EUn5ENTl-KOVD02PIwlyblw8ItjfOfhtQ/viewform'

const dropDownRootElemSelector = 'div.quantumWizMenuPaperselectEl'

const desiredOption = 'United Kingdom' // Write down your desired option here

;(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch ({
        headless: false,
        devtools: false
    })

    const [page] = await browser.pages ()

    const open = await page.goto ( formURL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0 } )

    while ( await page.evaluate ( dropDownRootElemSelector => !document.querySelector(dropDownRootElemSelector).classList.contains('isFocused'), dropDownRootElemSelector ) ) {
        await page.keyboard.press('Tab')
        await page.waitFor(250)
    }

    await page.keyboard.press('Space')

    while ( await page.evaluate ( dropDownRootElemSelector => document.querySelector(dropDownRootElemSelector).lastElementChild.childElementCount === 0, dropDownRootElemSelector ) ) {
        await page.waitFor(200)
    }

    const optionExist = async () => {
        await page.evaluate ( (dropDownRootElemSelector, desiredOption) => {

            var optionsDropDown = []

            document.querySelectorAll( dropDownRootElemSelector + ' > div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="presentation"] > div[role="option"] ~ div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="option"]').forEach(elem => optionsDropDown.push(elem.textContent) )

            return ( optionsDropDown.includes(desiredOption) )

        }, dropDownRootElemSelector, desiredOption)
    }

    if ( optionExist () ) {
        await page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown')
    }

    while ( await page.evaluate ( (dropDownRootElemSelector) => document.querySelector( dropDownRootElemSelector + ' > div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="presentation"] > div[role="option"] ~ div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="option"].isSelected') === null, dropDownRootElemSelector ) ) {
        await page.waitFor(250)
    }

    while ( optionExist () && await page.evaluate ( (dropDownRootElemSelector, desiredOption) => document.querySelector( dropDownRootElemSelector + ' > div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="presentation"] > div[role="option"] ~ div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="option"].isSelected').dataset.value !== desiredOption, dropDownRootElemSelector, desiredOption) ) {
        // console.log ( await page.evaluate ( (dropDownRootElemSelector) => document.querySelector( dropDownRootElemSelector + ' > div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="presentation"] > div[role="option"] ~ div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="option"].isSelected').dataset.value, dropDownRootElemSelector ) )
        await page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown')
        await page.waitFor(250)
    }

    await page.keyboard.press('Enter')


})()
```

If you have multiple dropdowns, then it's simple.

You can add a unique identifier at the selector, for this example, you can add `[data-item-id="ID_NUMBER"]` for each dropdown.

Don't forget to add delay by placing `await page.waitFor(1000)` at the end of every dropdown code to avoid unselected dropdown caused by fast running script.

Added new answer for multiple dropdown:

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer')

const formURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeY-5GpBQ7ww3qm-EUn5ENTl-KOVD02PIwlyblw8ItjfOfhtQ/viewform'

const dropDownRootCountrySelector = '[data-item-id="1058991397"] > div.quantumWizMenuPaperselectEl'
const dropDownRootZoneSelector = '[data-item-id="50474009"] > div.quantumWizMenuPaperselectEl'

const desiredCountry = 'United Kingdom' // Write down your desired option here
const desiredZone = 'Europe' // Write down your desired option here

;(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch ({
        headless: false,
        devtools: false
    })

    const [page] = await browser.pages ()

    const open = await page.goto ( formURL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0 } )

    // FIRST DROPDOWN => COUNTRY

    while ( await page.evaluate ( dropDownRootCountrySelector => !document.querySelector(dropDownRootCountrySelector).classList.contains('isFocused'), dropDownRootCountrySelector ) ) {
        await page.keyboard.press('Tab')
        await page.waitFor(250)
    }

    await page.keyboard.press('Space')

    while ( await page.evaluate ( dropDownRootCountrySelector => document.querySelector(dropDownRootCountrySelector).lastElementChild.childElementCount === 0, dropDownRootCountrySelector ) ) {
        await page.waitFor(200)
    }

    const optionExistCountry = async () => {
        await page.evaluate ( (dropDownRootCountrySelector, desiredCountry) => {

            var optionsDropDown = []

            document.querySelectorAll( dropDownRootCountrySelector + ' > div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="presentation"] > div[role="option"] ~ div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="option"]').forEach(elem => optionsDropDown.push(elem.textContent) )

            return ( optionsDropDown.includes(desiredCountry) )

        }, dropDownRootCountrySelector, desiredCountry)
    }

    if ( optionExistCountry () ) {
        await page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown')
    }

    while ( await page.evaluate ( (dropDownRootCountrySelector) => document.querySelector( dropDownRootCountrySelector + ' > div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="presentation"] > div[role="option"] ~ div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="option"].isSelected') === null, dropDownRootCountrySelector ) ) {
        await page.waitFor(250)
    }

    while ( optionExistCountry () && await page.evaluate ( (dropDownRootCountrySelector, desiredCountry) => document.querySelector( dropDownRootCountrySelector + ' > div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="presentation"] > div[role="option"] ~ div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="option"].isSelected').dataset.value !== desiredCountry, dropDownRootCountrySelector, desiredCountry) ) {
        // console.log ( await page.evaluate ( (dropDownRootCountrySelector) => document.querySelector( dropDownRootCountrySelector + ' > div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="presentation"] > div[role="option"] ~ div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="option"].isSelected').dataset.value, dropDownRootCountrySelector ) )
        await page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown')
        await page.waitFor(250)
    }

    await page.keyboard.press('Enter')

    await page.waitFor(1000)
    // SECOND DROPDOWN => ZONE

    while ( await page.evaluate ( dropDownRootZoneSelector => !document.querySelector(dropDownRootZoneSelector).classList.contains('isFocused'), dropDownRootZoneSelector ) ) {
        await page.keyboard.press('Tab')
        await page.waitFor(250)
    }

    await page.keyboard.press('Space')

    while ( await page.evaluate ( dropDownRootZoneSelector => document.querySelector(dropDownRootZoneSelector).lastElementChild.childElementCount === 0, dropDownRootZoneSelector ) ) {
        await page.waitFor(200)
    }

    const optionExistZone = async () => {
        await page.evaluate ( (dropDownRootZoneSelector, desiredZone) => {

            var optionsDropDown = []

            document.querySelectorAll( dropDownRootZoneSelector + ' > div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="presentation"] > div[role="option"] ~ div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="option"]').forEach(elem => optionsDropDown.push(elem.textContent) )

            return ( optionsDropDown.includes(desiredZone) )

        }, dropDownRootZoneSelector, desiredZone)
    }

    if ( optionExistZone () ) {
        await page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown')
    }

    while ( await page.evaluate ( (dropDownRootZoneSelector) => document.querySelector( dropDownRootZoneSelector + ' > div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="presentation"] > div[role="option"] ~ div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="option"].isSelected') === null, dropDownRootZoneSelector ) ) {
        await page.waitFor(250)
    }

    while ( optionExistZone () && await page.evaluate ( (dropDownRootZoneSelector, desiredZone) => document.querySelector( dropDownRootZoneSelector + ' > div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="presentation"] > div[role="option"] ~ div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="option"].isSelected').dataset.value !== desiredZone, dropDownRootZoneSelector, desiredZone) ) {
        // console.log ( await page.evaluate ( (dropDownRootZoneSelector) => document.querySelector( dropDownRootZoneSelector + ' > div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="presentation"] > div[role="option"] ~ div[role="presentation"] ~ div[role="option"].isSelected').dataset.value, dropDownRootZoneSelector ) )
        await page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown')
        await page.waitFor(250)
    }

    await page.keyboard.press('Enter')

})()
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution it does work very well and is works exactly with the scenario I described!

Comment: Related to the situation, I see it by selecting the root selector element it can navigate and select the desired option. However, I did come to an issue, that is there may be on the same page 2 dropdowns, and these dropdowns have the same root selector so it would not be able to navigate the second dropdown? Or at least, from my attempt, I could not get it to identify the second dropdown uniquely

Comment: This is the form updated with a second dropdown that has the same selector

Comment: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeY-5GpBQ7ww3qm-EUn5ENTl-KOVD02PIwlyblw8ItjfOfhtQ/viewform

Comment: i've edit my answer above, check it please.
You can add as many selector and function as you like.